# Searching Multiple Rows at a time through a single SQL query

Tags: sql, database

I have a table whose data is in this manner.

```
A B C
---------
0 6 2
0 3 4
1 0 2
1 1 4
```

I wrote a SQL query -

```
select A 
from Table 
where (B = 6 and C = 2) AND (B = 3 and C = 4).
```

Obviously it returned zero results since this query would search in the same row. Please help me with writing a better one to produce results such that it can check two rows with a single statement.

EDIT:
I am not looking for 'OR' statement. I need to find an element of A such that it has two corresponding rows AND each of the rows has elements 6,2 and 3,4 present in columns B,C correspondingly.

PS.

(I don't have the option of writing two queries and then finding the common elements of two set.)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like this

```
select A
from YourTable
where (B = 6 and C = 2) or 
      (B = 3 and C = 4)
group by A
having count(distinct B) >= 2
```

Try here:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123711/

Comment: When I tried the same query for (B = 0 and C = 2) or (B = 1 and C = 4), it gave me 1.

Comment: @killboi6174 Yes? That is the data for A=1. At least since you edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, for not making myself clear earlier. I meant that when I give something like (B = 0 and C = 2) or (B = 2 and C = 4), it still gives me 1 as if its checking to see whether condition holds true for at least a single row. But the desired result should be zero.

Comment: @killboi6174 - For me it gives no rows. Try here:http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123723/

Comment: That is because you have given the condition that B>=2 (which prompted me to edit the data in the first place). What if I need to find A such that corresponding elements in B,C are less than 2. I don't have any condition which can be presribed to elemnts under column B. I just have provided a sample table here

Comment: @killboi6174 There is no `B>=2` in the query. There is a `count(distinct B) >= 2` and that should not be changed when you change values in the where condition. The having clause is checking that you have at least 2 rows that match the condition. If you should need to check for the existence of three value pairs you should change the having clause to `count(distinct B) >= 3`.

Comment: I just checked this and found it working. Thnx for persisting with me

Comment: @killboi6174: The idea behind Mikael's solution is first to find rows matching either of the given value pairs (hence the linking `OR`, not `AND`), then to see whether the number of rows found matches the number of pairs, which is `2` on your case. What particular result should be returned, you are free to decide for yourself. Mikael's example returns the value(s) of `A` found (i.e. matching both conditions mentioned above). But you might want to change it the way you like, e.g. a constant `0` to mean `fail` (no rows) and `1` to mean `success`, or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Use **OR** instead of **AND**

```
select A from Table where (B=6 and C=2) OR (B=3 and C=4).
```

If you want the onlu result use DISTINCT

```
select DISTINCT A from Table where (B=6 and C=2) OR (B=3 and C=4).
```

If you need to check the equality of A, use this:

```
select t1.A 
from Table t1
JOIN Table t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
where T1.B=6 and t1.C=2 AND t2.B=3 and t2.C=4
```

As you see - using **AND** again

Comment: Both the rows have to be present and both need to contain aforementioned data. I was not looking for the 'OR' alternative

Comment: OR is not an alternative if you look for all the rows, the use the variant #1

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get this??

```
SELECT A 
FROM Table 
WHERE (B = 6 AND C = 2) OR (B = 3 AND C = 4)
```

This would return the `A` column for all four rows again.

If not: **WHAT** exactly are you trying to select?

IF you want just two rows, one with `A = 0`, one with `A = 1`, then use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A 
FROM Table 
WHERE (B = 6 AND C = 2) OR (B = 3 AND C = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
select A 
from Table 
where (B = 6 and C = 2)
INTERSECT
select A 
from Table 
(B = 3 and C = 4)
```

Comment: This is same as executing two queries and the original datatbases are quite heavy as opposed to the example I have provided.

Comment: If you don't like `intersect`, you can use inner join as Oleg Dok proposed, or you can also made subselect.